# Como detectar si un objeto pertenece a una lista

Tags: c#, linq

soy nuevo en esto y tengo un código lo que hace es generar un  mazo de cartas que lo ordena aleatoriamente para luego distribuir las cartas y lo que yo quiero hacer es identificar a cual de las cuatro primeras listas pertenece la carta de la muestra (es decir si es oro, copa, espada o basto) pero no estaría sabiendo como hacerlo.

```
public class MazoCartas : MonoBehaviour
{ 
    void Start()
    {
        var cartasOro = new List<string>() { "O1", "O2", "O3", "O4", "O5", "O6", "O7", "OJ", "OQ", "OK" };
        var cartasCopa = new List<string>() { "C1", "C2", "C3", "C4", "C5", "C6", "C7", "CJ", "CQ", "CK" };
        var cartasEspada = new List<string>() { "E1", "E2", "E3", "E4", "E5", "E6", "E7", "EJ", "EQ", "EK" };
        var cartasBasto = new List<string>() { "B1", "B2", "B3", "B4", "B5", "B6", "B7", "BJ", "BQ", "BK" };
        var deck = new List<string>() {};
        deck.AddRange(cartasOro);
        deck.AddRange(cartasCopa);
        deck.AddRange(cartasEspada);
        deck.AddRange(cartasBasto);
    
        List<string> shuffledDeck = deck.OrderBy(item => Random.Range(0, deck.Count)).ToList();

        //Crea listas vacias para las diferentes cosas
        List<string> playerCards = new List<string>();
        List<string> opponentCards = new List<string>();
        List<string> muestraCards = new List<string>();  

        //distribuye las cartas a jugadores
        playerCards.AddRange(shuffledDeck.Take(3));
        shuffledDeck.RemoveRange(index: 0, count: 3);

        opponentCards.AddRange(shuffledDeck.Take(3));
        shuffledDeck.RemoveRange(index: 0, count: 3);

        muestraCards.AddRange(shuffledDeck.Take(1));
        shuffledDeck.RemoveRange(index: 0, count: 1);

        //Esto hace que las cartas se escriban en la consola (despues seguro se borra esto)
        foreach(var card in playerCards)
        {
            Debug.Log($"Cartas del jugador: {card}");
        }
        foreach(var card in opponentCards)
        {
            Debug.Log($"Cartas del oponente: {card}");
        }
        foreach(var card in muestraCards)
        {
            Debug.Log($"Carta de la muestra: {card}");
            if(card == cartasOro)
            {
                Debug.Log("Si");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Se que el código esta mal por el final pero es para mostrar lo que estoy intentando hacer.

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes, revisa https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour para que veas la dinámica del sitio y de paso obtengas tu primera medalla, del mismo modo, revisa https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=net-8.0 Me late que es lo que estás buscando.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Espero te ayude

```
foreach(var card in muestraCards)
    {
        Debug.Log($"Carta de la muestra: {card}");
        if(cartasOro.Contains(card))
        {
            Debug.Log("La carta de la muestra es de oro.");
        }
        else if(cartasCopa.Contains(card))
        {
            Debug.Log("La carta de la muestra es de copa.");
        }
        else if(cartasEspada.Contains(card))
        {
            Debug.Log("La carta de la muestra es de espada.");
        }
        else if(cartasBasto.Contains(card))
        {
            Debug.Log("La carta de la muestra es de basto.");
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("La carta de la muestra no pertenece a ningún palo conocido.");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y describe cómo este código responde a la pregunta. Lee [answer].

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar el **método Any** de **Linq**:

```
if (cartasOro.Any(c => c == miCarta))
{
    //Está en mazo de las cartas de oro
}
else if (cartasCopa.Any(c => c == miCarta))
{
    //Está en mazo de las cartas de copa
}
else if (cartasEspada.Any(c => c == miCarta))
{
    //Está en mazo de las cartas de espada
}
else if (cartasBasto.Any(c => c == miCarta))
{
    //Está en mazo de las cartas de basto
}
```

Lo que se hace aquí es buscar en cada lista si nuestra carta se encuentra en alguna de éstas lista.

**Importante**: A la carta a buscar yo le doy el nombre de **miCarta** para poderte explicar bien. Debes revisar en tu código como escoges la carta que deseas buscar y usar el algoritmo que te explico más arriba.